# javascript Split string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following 2 string which I supposed to split according to delimiter: '/' or "/*"

my code:

```
var move = "1/2/13/14";
var results = move.split(new RegExp("[/\*?]"));
```

results are GOOD:

```
["1","2","13","14"]
```

BUT, for the next example:

```
var move = "1/*2/13/*14";
var results = move.split(new RegExp("[/\*?]"));
```

I get BAD results:

```
["1","","2","13","","14"]
```

Why?? How can I modify it to work correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you expect the outcome to be? Just like the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `[]`, you are creating a character class, which means "any one of these symbols". This means your regex is looking for the literal characters `/`, `*` (needlessly escaped in char class), *or* `?` for splitting. The `*` and `?` do not take on their meta functionality inside the character class.

The regex you'll want is `/\/\*?/` (as a regex literal), or with the constructor `new RegExp("/\\*?")`. You do not need the character class.

Answer (score 3):

You can just make `*` optional after `/`:

```
"1/*2/13/*14".split( /\/\*?/ );
["1", "2", "13", "14"]

"1/2/13/14".split( /\/\*?/ );
["1", "2", "13", "14"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having problems because you are grouping the characters with the brackets .`[` and `]`).  In a regular expression, those characters will allow any of the characters within the group to be matched.

If you remove them like this: `var results = move.split(new RegExp("/\\*?"));`, you should get the results that you want.

Answer (score 0):

This one helps:

```
move.split(new RegExp("[/][*]?"));
```

Comment: @eldarerathis just for the record, a single `\ ` in the character class with `*` would have no impact, as it is interpreted as the escape symbol. it would take a double backslash to cause trouble ( `move.split(/[/][\\*]?/)`; nb: the `RegExp` constructor takes a string as its argument, thus a double escape would apply, thus it takes `new RegExp("[/][\\\\*]?")` to fail). Anyway, you are perfectly right that the escaping inside the character class is superfluous.